# I want to extract href from a website using BeautifulSoup. href is inside a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

The code goes something like this:

```
<div class="browse"> 
<a href="xxx" > abc </a> 
<a href="zzz"> xyz </a>
</div>
```

I want to get the data 'xxx' and 'zzz' using BS4. There are several divisions on a webpage who have a format like this. All those links are different and the text they contain is also different. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Given a text file foo.txt with the following

```
<div class="browse">
<a href="xxx" > abc</a></div>
<div class="browse">
<a href="yyy" > abc</a></div>

>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
>>> html = open("foo.txt").read()
>>> soup = bs4(html)
>>> [a.attrs for sub in soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"browse"}) for a in sub.findAll('a')]
[{'href': 'xxx'}, {'href': 'yyy'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have used find_all to get all the data having class="browse"

If you don't post a simple example with your code, we can't tell what you are doing wrong.  Here is an example of what you can do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="browse">
<a href="xxx"> abc</a>
</div>

<div> 
<a href="yyy"> abc</a>
</div>

<div class="browse"> 
<a href="zzz" > abc</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
divs = soup.find_all('div', {"class": "browse"})

for div in divs:
    print(div.a['href'])

--output:--
xxx
zzz
```

> The code goes something like this:
>
> ```
> <div class="browse"> 
> <a href="xxx" > abc</a> .
> ```

Great example. :(

If your html actually looks like this:

```
html = """
<div class="browse">
<a href="xxx"> abc</a>

<div> 
<a href="yyy"> abc</a>

<div class="browse"> 
<a href="zzz" > abc</a>
"""
```

Then bs4 parses that as:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="browse">
   <a href="xxx">
    abc
   </a>
   <div>
    <a href="yyy">
     abc
    </a>
    <div class="browse">
     <a href="zzz">
      abc
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Notice how the div tags are nested inside each other. I don't know if that was giving you trouble or not--but the code above will still work.

Comment: HTML code looks like this:

`code`

<div class='browse'>
<a href='zzz'>abc</a>
</div>
<div class='browse'>
<a href='xxx'>pqr</a>
</div>

`code`

Comment: @SiddharthPathak, Okay, then see my example. The html has a div without class="browse" to show that the code skips that div. –